# Validate phone number using Antd, type="number" not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, antd

I'm new to this.. I've been trying to validate phone number but it isn't working. What corrections should be made? I've attached the code snippet and result below.

```
<Form.Item
        label="Phone Number"
        name="phone"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please Input Your Phone Number!',
          },
          { 
            type: "number",
            message: 'Please enter a valid phone number!', 
          },
        ]}
>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFHW2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for validate phone number in antd, you should use patterns and regex.
for example:

```
rules: [
      {
        required: true,
        type: "regexp",
        pattern: new RegExp(/\d+/g),
        message: "Wrong format!"
      }
    ]
```

and naturaly, you should add your desired pattern instead of my example